# How to turn off triggers for a specific period on Zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I want to disable the Zabbix trigger only between 01:00 - 05:00. It should be enabled after 05:00 until 01:00 again.

```
and time(...) > 050000 and time(...) < 010000
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. I know about the `Maintenance` function on Zabbix, but that is not an option.

What's wrong with above code or does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: Could you post your full trigger? Maintenance with data collection is the easiest answer, why isn't an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've solved the problem with this trigger :

`({server:net.tcp.listen[22].last()}=0 and {server:net.tcp.listen[22].time()}>050000) or ({server:net.tcp.listen[22].last()}=0 and {server:net.tcp.listen[22].time()}<010000)`

it seems to work for me ;-)